# HTML in JSON that "should" not be there

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have `description` field in  a form.

As suggested here, HTML escaping should not be done in input, so if you put `<h1>Description</h1>` it is saved like this to database.

The problem is that I have defined a REST API, and the output "could" be HTML.

Should I escape the field when constructing the JSON or should I output HTML in JSON and let the client escape it?.

I feel I should escape the HTML server side, but then this operation would cost processing time. On the other hand, escaping in HTML saves this server time, but people using the API not carefully escaping HTML could end with XSS attacks.

Comment: I wouldn't escape HTML within JSON data - if the client expects JSON then I think it's up to them to handle it as needed, noting that the client may not be displaying the data it in a browser.

Comment: how about 1) retrieve json from server, 2) escape html only for those who care for security (using some flag) 3) send over http.

Comment: @Shaurabh Sorry, what?

Comment: i meant "db" not server.. but anyways your answer clarifies the issue

Comment: Is this a public API or is it more internal on some intranet where you have some degree of control and/or trust?  Kind of curious about the entirety of the system.  To say, "don't worry about the client's security" is, in a way, neglecting the incompetence of others.

Comment: @vol7ron Are you advocating that the values *should* be pre-escaped by the server? Then that *requires* the client to be incompetent, otherwise they're seeing garbage data, or have to do extra work to clean the data.

Comment: Not at all, I'm suggesting that there isn't a right answer and the best solution often depends on the conditions of the environment.  If the results are to be used in some feed (imagine RSS) written by someone else, which won't be updated and that feed is going to represent your company, it would be best to help the end result as much as possible.  The talent, knowledge, and expertise differs from business to business and that has to be taken into consideration.  If this is an import form, there should already be some degree of sanitization/scrubbing.

Comment: At the same time, as a purist and as a user of a service, I would like to see the mostly raw input.  Like what @ShaurabhBharti said, if the system allows it (storage and performance), both could be stored in the RDBMS; ultimately to be determined by the client code.  However, I don't disagree with your answer.

Comment: Agh. I mixed this question up with another one about removing HTML elements entirely to prevent XSS attacks -- that's what I get when I leave and come back to many tabs open.  While most of these comments kind of  apply, some of this makes a lot less sense in context to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A client may, probably *will*, be a Javascript client which *should* process such potential HTML values using the DOM API:

```
document.getElementById('output').textContent = json.result;
```

Using this DOM API is perfectly safe and does not require to escape `json.result`, **since it's never interpolated as HTML**, but treated as text node by a higher level API. If you send escaped HTML and the client is doing it properly like here, then escaped HTML will be shown on the client; i.e. you're turning your data into garbage.

So, no, never escape values for unrelated contexts. Escape/encode for JSON when putting values into JSON, don't worry about what may or may not happen later.